# How to get the dates of the current monday, wednesday and friday of the current week in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I'd just like a simple formula to return the date for the current Monday, Wednesday and Friday based on the current date.

So, I would like to see it like:

- Cell A1 I'd like (Today is Monday January 9 2012)
- Cell B1 I'd like (Wednesday January 11 2012)
- Cell C1 I'd like (Friday January 13 2012).

Comment: Do you mean the Monday, Wednesday and Friday of the current week?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following will display the dates for Monday, Wednesday and Friday of the current week:

```
=NOW() - WEEKDAY(NOW(),3)
=NOW() - WEEKDAY(NOW(),3)+2
=NOW() - WEEKDAY(NOW(),3)+4
```

Basically this is taking the time now, and subtracting the current weekday (which gives you Monday), then adds 2 days or 4 days to get Wednesday and Friday.

Comment: You may consider using `TODAY()` instead of `NOW()` as the latter returns the time as well, which make it slightly less clean if further computation is needed.

Answer (score 7):

Sunday of this current week:

```
=1-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()
```

Monday of this current week:

```
=2-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()
```

Tuesday of this current week:

```
=3-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()
```

Wednesday of this current week:

```
=4-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()
```

Thursday of this current week:

```
=5-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()
```

Friday of this current week:

```
=6-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()
```

Saturday of this current week:

```
=7-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()
```

SUNDAY of following week, when Monday & not Sunday is used as day #1 of week:

```
=8-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()
```

Also, if you change the *format* of the cell to a **custom format** and choose `DDD` it will display **Fri** or **Mon** and if you use `DDDD` it will display **Friday** or **Monday**, etc.

Comment: When using the weekday function with a Return_Type here are the options: no ,Return_type = = 1 (Sunday) through 7 (Saturday) 1 = 1 (Sunday) through 7 (Saturday) 2 = 1 (Monday) through 7 (Sunday) 3 = 0 (Monday) through 6 (Sunday)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to say today is something or another:

```
=CONCATENATE("Today is ",TEXT(6-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY(),"DDDD"),".")
```

This would return: **Today is Friday**.

And this:

```
=CONCATENATE("Today is ",TEXT(6-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY(),"DDDD MMM DD"),".")
```

Would return: **Today is Friday Jan 13**.